# Who knows what part this is?

Tags: identification, components

does anyone know what part this is?

I suspect it's some kind of tvs or reverse polarity protection diode.
I can read what's written on it, but can't find anything on the internet with the info.
Obviously it's a part from ST, but other than that I'm totally blank.

[image: Diode]

For those who can't read it, it says:

```
ST G
EX
Z239
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: To answer the question in the title, "Who knows what part this is?", Rohat Kılıç does!

Comment: Also listed here: https://smd.yooneed.one/code4558.html

Comment: @Transistor I'm updating my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @EeEmDee poll type questions are off topic here ... why do you need a list of people with certain knowledge?

Comment: @EeEmDee, we're having a little fun at your expense, but there's a gentle hint to write more carefully. You can see Rohit's answer in the "edited" link or in the micro-text at the bottom of his answer.

Comment: Hahaha guys, thanks for the little hint :) And thanks for the answer @RohatKılıç :*
Honestly, that was hilarious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does anyone know what part this is?

I do.

<sub><sup><sub><sup>It's [SM6T39A](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/6f/2d/a6/9e/56/51/48/15/CD00000725.pdf/files/CD00000725.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000725.pdf), a unidirectional TVS from ST.</sup></sub></sup></sub>